# filter a json column element in where clause

Tags: postgresql

I have a below query in PostgreSQL:

```
select a.request_id,a.job_type from
(
   select request_id,
       job_id ->> 0 as job_id_1, 
       job_id ->> 1 as job_id_2
   from job_requests_table 
) tab
inner join job_requests_table a
on a.request_id = tab.request_id
where cast(tab.job_id_1 as varchar) like '%test-cluster-id-11111%';
```

This is working find since **test-cluster-id-11111** was found as an first element of job_id column.
It could be at any place and also `job_id` column can have one element also or more than one also.. could be four or five.

I was looking for some solution that I should not specify that it has to be compare for specific position in where clause

```
where cast(tab.job_id_1 as varchar) like '%test-cluster-id-11111%';
```

and also in inner query it has to be like if it has one element it should generate one instance of that column and if it has **'n'** elements then it should generate those many instances.

```
select request_id,
       job_id ->> 0 as job_id_1, 
       job_id ->> 1 as job_id_2
from job_requests_table
```

`job_id` column is of `json` type and can have multiple elements like

```
["test-cluster-id-11111", "test-cluster-id-22222","test-cluster-id-33333"]
```

Why isn't this working?

```
select request_id,unnest(string_to_array(job_id, ',')) as element from job_requests_table;
```

Comment: why this is not working?  select request_id,unnest(string_to_array(job_id, ',')) as element from job_requests_table;

Comment: Welcome to DBA.SE. The question you are asking doesn't contain enough information. Could you add some sample data to your question for **all columns** in the table? Possibly the DDL of the involved table and what issues you are facing? Please also consider adding your comments directly in the question. (Hit the [edit] button and add the details to the question.) Comments aren't well suited to transport relevant information as they don't format well. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `?` operator to test for the existence of a string in a JSON array:

```
from job_requests_table 
where job_id ? 'test-cluster-id-11111'
```

If you really need a LIKE condition, you will have to use a sub-query

```
from job_requests_table  t
where exists (select * 
              from json_array_elements(t.job_id) as i(item)
              where item like '%1111%')
```

Comment: Thanks.. second worked perfectly.. am I missing something in first one?  select * from job_requests_table where job_id ? 'test-cluster-id-11111';   and I got this "HINT:  No operator matches the given name and argument type(s). You might need to add explicit type casts."

Comment: `?` only works for `jsonb` columns. I assumed you were using that (as that is the recommended data type for storing JSON values). But apparently you are using `json` which does not support that operator. you can cast the column `job_id::jsonb ? ...` or better: change it permanently to `jsonb`

Comment: Thanks. It worked like a charm

Comment: Is it possible to use like operator with ? as well.. something like "? like '%AAA%';"